# How can I populate a sparse UITableView from a fetched results object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

In my sweet app you can use two kinds of items from a list of items. There are equipable items, and bag items. When you navigate to the inventory screen, there are two sections of a table view, each with 4 cells. Four cells for equipped items, and four cells for items in your "bag". If you don't have anything equipped, the cells just say "empty".

How can I populate table cells conditionally based on the shape of my results object?

Here is the code I wish I had:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  // this returns 'nil' if the index path was out of bounds
  NSManagedObject * item = [self.fetchedResultsController carefullyGetObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (nil == item) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"empty"; 

  } else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [item valueForKey:@"name"];

  }

}
```

Some problems I've encountered trying to implement this 'careful' objectAtIndexPath:

I tried bounds checking, but I'm having trouble because the fetchedArray is flat, while the  conceptual model I am trying to navigate is not flat: rows are 'in' sections.

I tried using a try/catch, but then I remembered that the out-of-bounds elements are undefined, not nil... so sometimes I get an error that I can catch and react to, and sometimes I just get random interesting stuff. The setup I have now:

```
@try {

  NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  return managedObject;
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
  return nil;
}
```

consistently gives me 5 entries, 4 in the right places and 1 odd-ball which is a repeat from the other section.

Not sure how to navigate the fetched results manually. I'm playing with four items, 2 of each kind. I had hoped it would be as easy as a doubly nested array, with sections on the outside and rows on the in. It seems that things are trickier than this. When I inspect the fetchedResults NSArray, I see that it is flat. All the "bag" items are first, and the "equipable" come next. I don't imagine I can depend on this ordering, though, so I don't feel safe making a mapping function to go from indexPath section to array index. (I could be convinced to feel safe about this).

An alternative I thought of involves populating my inventory with 8 'empty' items that would be returned as place holder results when the sections don't get completely filled. This doesn't sit well with me though.

I realize why this isn't working: tables aren't supposed to have 'empty' rows. But I want my table to have empty rows!

**UPDATE**

Here's the method I'm using for now...

```
- (NSManagedObject*) carefullyGetObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
  NSLog(@"in %@ %s", [self class], _cmd);

  NSString * desiredType = (indexPath.section == BAG_SECTION)? @"bag" : @"equipable";
  NSArray * fetchedObjects = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
  NSInteger sectionStartIndex = -1;

  // iterate until you hit a type you like
  NSUInteger i, count = [fetchedObjects count];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSObject * obj = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * fetchedType = (NSString*)[obj valueForKey:@"type"];

    if ([desiredType isEqualToString:fetchedType]) {
      sectionStartIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (-1 == sectionStartIndex) {
    // maybe there aren't any of that type of item

  } else {

    NSInteger calculatedEntityIndex = sectionStartIndex + indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"calculated index %d", calculatedEntityIndex);

    // if we are still in the array
    if (calculatedEntityIndex < [fetchedObjects count]) {

      // then we can get the object
      NSManagedObject * entity = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:calculatedEntityIndex];

      // and if we are still in the right section
      NSString * typeForEntityAtIndex = [entity valueForKey:@"type"];

      if ([desiredType isEqualToString:typeForEntityAtIndex]) {
        // then this is what we wanted

        return entity;
      }
    }
  }

  return nil;   
}
```

I just really don't feel I should have to iterate over something like this...

z.

Full disclosure: this is a term project, but the project is to make the app by any means necessary. This includes third party libraries, asking questions on stackoverflow, &c... The goal of this term project is to experience working on something bigger, like a sweet app, not to learn objective-c.

Comment: Look here for custom tableviews, http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 1):

Ziggy,

The `NSFetchedResultsController` has many limitations. If you cannot make your schema meet its exacting requirements and it appears you probably haven't, then you should construct your `tableView` out of multiple `NSFetchRequest`s. It is straightforward. Most of the interesting `tableView`s do just this. Core Data really works best when you perform larger fetches and then refine the search using the set and filter operations on the collection classes.

`tableView`s can have empty rows. You just have to coordinate this with custom code in your various delegate and cell configuration code.

You have a lot of options to solve your problem. It appears you are unhappy with a quite limited framework API. You're a budding programmer. Roll your own.

Andrew

P.S. You have a curious goal to write a Mac OS X/iOS app without needing to learn Objective-C. You actually have chosen the one technology in the framework, Core Data, that exercises Objective-C to its maximum capability. (In my opinion, as an educator of iOS programmers, your education would probably be better served learning the intricacies of a very different persistence model, Core Data's model, than retreating to mundane, mainstream SQL solution.) If you would prefer to use a different language, MacRuby/RubyMotion is quite effective.

Comment: Great food for thought! By the way, not learning objective-C wasn't my goal: I like objective-C and I like learning new languages. I just wanted to clarify that, answering this question would not conflict with the homework tag (since the question arose from the homework and was not itself the homework).